# UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect memory leak

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-leaks

I am performing some profiling on my application. I have a method that computes a `CGRect` and based on that returns a `UIBezierPath`.

The `Leaks` tool in `XCode Instruments` is displaying memory leaks with the `UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:` method. Did anyone else experience this sort of issue? Is there any possibility that this may be a false positive?

I tested on both an iPhone 5s and iPhone 5c and the results are the same. Here are some shots from my `Instruments` (fig. 1 is the line description of the leaking method, fig. 2 is the leaks captured by instruments, both leading to this method):

[image: Line description in Instruments]

[image: Captured leaks]

Edit: code excerpt

```
- (UIBezierPath *)boundaryPath {
  CGRect boundary = CGRectZero;
UIBezierPath *bezierPath;
boundary.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(self.paneView.frame)/2;
boundary.size.height = CGRectGetHeight(self.tightWindow.frame);

if (CGRectGetMinX(self.tightWindow.frame) > 0) {
boundary.origin.x = 0.0f;
boundary.origin.y = 0.0f;
} else {
boundary.origin.x = CGRectGetMinX(self.paneView.frame);
boundary.origin.y = CGRectGetMinY(self.paneView.frame);
}

bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:boundary];

return bezierPath;
}
```

Edit 2 - method usage

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollisionBehavior *paneBoundaryCollisionBehavior;

...

[self.paneBoundaryCollisionBehavior removeAllBoundaries];
[self.paneBoundaryCollisionBehavior addBoundaryWithIdentifier:identifier forPath:[self boundaryPath]];
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Can you please other relevant code (e.g. the usage of this method) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

can you please describe something about the code.
Well in my case i was having the problem like with returning the `CGPath`. The value returned is a `CGPathRef` which is not covered by **ARC**. The `UIBezierPath` you create is released after the method ends. Thus also freeing the `CGPathRef`. You can specify a source annotation to let ARC know your intent:

In the .h file:

```
-(CGPathRef)makeToPath CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;
-(CGPathRef)makeFromPath CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;
```

Hope this help!!